# CRM 2013 - Plugin fires before JavaScript OnSave

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Coming up against a problem on CRM 2013, I have a plugin that is set fire on save of an opportunity.

I have some code set on a field's on change event which sets the value of another field.

I am coming across a couple of issues:

1. If the user doesn't tab out of the field the record gets saved without the updated value.
2. If I set any JavaScript to fire 'onSave' the plugin seems to fire first? The plugin is set to run synchronously on post save.

Anyone else had similar problems?

Thanks

Ant

Comment: Are you calling Xrm.Page.data.save() in the javascript events?

Comment: 1) This is normal behaviour as the underlying value in the model (that which gets posted back to the server) doesn't get changed until the control loses focus.  2) Do you have autosave enabled on the form?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Darren, yes I understand that this is standard functionality it was more a question of the 2nd point really. No i dont have auto save enabled and no I am not calling save from within Javascript. I have JS code that runs on save which I would expect to fire prior to the post operation plugin was fired? What seems to be happening though is the plugin fires before the Javascript has been executed strangely.

Comment: For example on save I force focus on another textbox to ensure the value gets updated but the plugin still gets the old value.

Comment: As I know, there is two types. Are you sure, your plugin setup as post-Save ? maybe it can be pre, so it gets the old value.

Comment: @DarrenLewis I am confused if your reply to point 1 is true then why when I change a ticker symbol value in an account record (for example) and click bottom right save button without loosing the focus, the modified value gets saved? I am using Chrome browser.

Comment: Can you post you Javascript logic and your plug-in logic.

Comment: If the user doesn't tab out or click somewhere outside the field, the onchange won't be triggered and then the form will automatically save which will trigger the plugin. You could do the stuff you want to happen in the script in the plugin also to make sure it happens.